# How do transformers work?

Tags: transformer, induction, emf

I am a recent EE graduate and never really understood how transformers work.

I am having trouble understanding how voltage is increased at the expense of current in a step up transformer.

I understand energy has to be conserved, but according to Ohms Law, current increases with increased voltage. I understand this increase in current comes from the source, the magnetic flux in the primary reduces its impedance which results in higher current which is proportional to the load connected at the secondary. I can’t seem to recall the equations that model this. I struggled with EMf courses and so did all my classmates.

Comment: "according to Ohms Law". Ohm's law applies to resistors. Transformers are not resistors so Ohm's law doesn't apply directly to them. (It does apply just to their DC resistance -- not the complete transformer -- , but that's not what a transformer uses to work.)

Answer (score 5):

As long as energy is conserved, circuit elements can have arbitrary voltage-vs-current curves. Up to a point where the current and voltage are completely independent:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP1HeZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltage across the two nodes in this circuit, and the current flowing in the loop, are independent.

Now imagine that this thing is an ideal transformer winding. Et voila. No Ohm's law anywhere.

Ohm's law relates current and voltage in impedances. Not every circuit element is can be modeled as just a complex impedance. A transformer winding with other windings disconnected is approximately a complex (inductive) impedance. But as soon as that transformer is delivering energy to that winding from other windings, it's not just an impedance, but an impedance in series with an EMF.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a transformer with a 10:1 turns ratio. If you put 100 VAC on the primary you will get 1/10th of that or 10 VAC on the secondary.

Now put a 1\$\Omega\$ load on the secondary, the secondary current will be 10 A. What will the primary current be?

You have to look at the impedance. A transformer transforms the impedance as the square of the turns ratio, so 100:1. If the secondary sees 1\$\Omega\$ the primary will look like 100\$\Omega\$ and the current will be 1 A, 1/10th of the secondary current. That’s all you need to remember, voltage is turns ratio, current is inverse of turns ratio, and impedance is square of turns ratio, simple.

Answer (score 1):

The equation for Emf is:

Emf = 4.44 * f * Fi * N  [Volts]

(Fi is flux, f is frequency, N is number of turns)

This formula is valid for primary side and the secondary also.
So, for the same flux created from primary if you increase secondary N you also increase the secondary Emf.

The currents goes inverted since:

N * i = H * l

(H*l consider constant)

Increased secondary turns causes decreased secondary current.

Btw, transformer doesn’t conserve energy except very low magnetising current. Ideally all energy is transferred to secondary.
The inductors store an energy.

Comment: Transformers do conserve energy, like everything else. "conserve energy" here means "don't generate energy out of nothing", not "store energy".

Comment: (And some transformers *do* need to store energy, like those used in flyback converters.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a relatively simple way of understanding the voltage and current ratios of an ideal transformer. You start with a simple ideal transformer that has only one turn on the primary winding and one turn on the secondary. Such a transformer does not step up or down so the current and voltage on the primary and secondary are the same (this can be derived from the equations, but in my opinion that is not necessary for understanding ratios, so this fact will be taken as is). Now imagine taking the secondary wire and splitting it into two wires that are connected at the end. You now have two wires with the same voltage as before, but each is carrying half of the current. If you now take the ends, split them as well and connect the two turns in series, you will double the voltage, and the current of both halves will stay the same - half of the primary current.

Comment: For further references, you can see Electrical Machines by BL Theraja (if you already have not).

Answer (score 0):

In a transformer, alternating current in the primary is converted to an alternating magnetic field.  The alternating magnetic field is then converted to current in the secondary.

As for stepping up or down:  Whatever voltage you apply to the primary, result in a certain number of volts per turn. (Divide primary voltage by primary turns, to get this number.) The magnetic field thus generated affects the secondary, inducing the same number of volts per turn. If the secondary side has twice the number of turns, you gets twice the voltage there. The number of volts per turn has to match, because it is the same magnetic field for both sides.

When it comes to current, the transformer cannot change the amount of power going through it. Output power equals input power (minus some losses.) Now, power is the product of voltage and current. So when voltage doubles, current must be halved. The power stays the same on both sides.

Ohm's law deals with resistance. It is not relevant for an ideal transformer. It may be used to calculate heating losses in real-world non-ideal transformers though.  The most interesting calculation is the winding ratio, which is also the voltage ratio and the inverse of the current ratio.

If you connect a load, such as a resistor, to the secondary:  use the stepped-up voltage to find the secondary-side current.  On the primary side, you will then find that the transformer draws a stepped-up current from its voltage source.